# ExpressJs - NODEMAILER not sending email on production mode using vercel

Tags: javascript, express, google-oauth, nodemailer, vercel

im really stuck here. i already try a couple hours to solve this. on development, nodemailer works for sending email, like verification or reset password. but when i deploy or on production mode using vercel, nodemailer not work. can somebody help me? please? i really stuck here. thank you. here's the code

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const fs = require("fs");
const mustache = require("mustache");
const path = require("path");
const gmail = require("../config/gmail");

module.exports = {
  sendMail: (data) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-new
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 465,
        auth: {
          type: "OAuth2",
          user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
          pass: process.env.APP_PASSWORD,
          clientId: gmail.clientId,
          clientSecret: gmail.clientSecret,
          refreshToken: gmail.refreshToken,
          accessToken: gmail.accessToken,
        },
        secure: "true",
      });

      const filePath = path.join(
        __dirname,
        `../../src/templates/email/${data.template}`
      );

      const fileTemplate = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");
      const mailOptions = {
        from: '"Event Organizing" <arkawebdev1@gmail.com>',
        to: data.to,
        subject: data.subject,
        html: mustache.render(fileTemplate, { ...data }),
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Whats the error message that you are getting?

Comment: hello bharath. thank you for respon, on the vercel there's no error, for create new user is success. but on my app, the user have to verified first. that's the problem, i still dont know how to trace the error from nodemailer on vercel

Comment: Build logs as mentioned in the [link](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs), then we can see whats the issue.